# After Symfony Upgrade 6.0 always redirecting to Login

Tags: symfony, security

i updated Symfony to 6.0. Since i updated my Project i cant reach any Page, because i always get redirected to the Login and end up in a loop that redirects me to the login. So i always end with the Error "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS".

I used the docs for upgrading https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/upgrade_major.html
My Security.yaml looks like that:

```
security:
    enable_authenticator_manager: true
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#registering-the-user-hashing-passwords
    password_hashers:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'auto'
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: auto

        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#loading-the-user-the-user-provider
    providers:
        users_in_memory: { memory: null }
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: email
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            lazy: true
            provider: app_user_provider
            form_login:
                login_path: login
                check_path: login
            logout:
                path: app_logout
                target: index
            # activate different ways to authenticate
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#the-firewall

            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
            # switch_user: true

    # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
    # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/product/create, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/favourite/add, roles: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: ^/favourite/remove, roles: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: ^/status, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: '^/', roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https }

when@test:
    security:
        password_hashers:
            # By default, password hashers are resource intensive and take time. This is
            # important to generate secure password hashes. In tests however, secure hashes
            # are not important, waste resources and increase test times. The following
            # reduces the work factor to the lowest possible values.
            Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface:
                algorithm: auto
                cost: 4 # Lowest possible value for bcrypt
                time_cost: 3 # Lowest possible value for argon
                memory_cost: 10 # Lowest possible value for argon
```

Comment: You may want to remove `users_in_memory`.

Also, where did you put your `role_hierarchy`?

My guess it's due to access_controll trying to take you into each routes.

Can you post your `AppAuthenticator` class?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY` is now `PUBLIC_ACCESS`

Try to change access_control like this:

```
access_control:
    ...
    - { path: '^/', roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS, requires_channel: https }
```

You can check the new documentation here https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#allowing-unsecured-access-i-e-anonymous-users

Comment: Thx man, i forgot the 5.4 minor update and thats why i didnt see the deprecation message